# how to check which constructor does the user use

Tags: java, string

I have my constructor like this

```
    public Name(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);        
}

public Name(String firstName, String lastName, String middleName)
{
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setMiddleName(middleName);
}
```

And I want to override my toString() method like this

```
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if(no middle name)
        {return  getFirstName() + " " + getLastName();}
        else if(has a middle name)
        {return  getFirstName() + " " + getMiddleName() + " " + getLastName();}
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like you should check whether `middleName` is null or empty...

Comment: Yeah, I'm with Jon Skeet. Your pseudocode works, you just have to implement it? If you want to check which constructor was used, you could also set a private field `constructorUsed` with an identifier for the constructor used, but I can't think of a real use-case for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    if(middleName == null)
    {return  getFirstName() + " " + getLastName();}
    else
    {return  getFirstName() + " " + getMiddleName() + " " + getLastName();}
}
```

You might want to check out [Guava's Strings](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) for isNullOrEmpty(), e.g. (and with only a single `return` which, as riccardo.cardin points out, is better practice):

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String nameString = null;

    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(middleName))
    {
        nameString = getFirstName() + " " + getLastName();
    }
    else
    {
        nameString = getFirstName() + " " + getMiddleName() + " " + getLastName();
    }

    return nameString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, did not know I can check in this way.

Comment: @jbrown, please do not have multiple `return`s in a single method. And do not use  `String` concatenation (`+` operator): use a `StringBuilder` or the method  `String.format(...)`.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin According to other SO answers, compilers will optimise concatenation into StringBuilders automatically, so concatenation gives more readable code with the same benefits. If the code was in a loop a StringBuilder would be more efficient, but here it's unnecessary.

Comment: @jbrown, sorry you're right. But the story about multiple `return` statements remains ;)

Comment: I think the code is more readable with two return statements. I see no reason to avoid it in this case. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement for a lot of discussion on this topic.

Comment: Bikeshedding, but I generally agree that fewer returns are a better habit to get into.